# Sharing State between two or more SIP Servlet servers

Tags: sip, sip-servlet, cipango

I'm writing a SIP Servlet application using Cipango.  The inevitable question has come up about how to scale this thing horizontally.  If I front the cluster of SIP Servlet boxes with a load balancer, how can I ensure that SIP sessions will be accessible from all servers.  Is it possible to store in a shared data store such as say Redis or BigCouch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobicents Sip Servlets leverages JBoss Application Server which will allow for SipSession and SipApplicationSession replication.  http://www.mobicents.org/clustering.html